# Android Room database created 3 files including -shm and -wal files

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, android-room

I have created a database using Room database library with name ImageDatabase, when I opened my Device File explorer in Android studio inside the database folder there were three files with names ImageDatabase, ImageDatabase-shm and ImageDatabase-wal. I wanted to know what are these files meant for? Any help would be great
Thanx All

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The data in your database is contained in all three.  The one with no extension is the main database.  The others are the **W**rite **A**head **L**og file (`-wal`) and the **Sh**ared **M**emory file (`-shm`).  They are used by the underlying SQLite system to improve performance, and contain the latest changes to the main database until a [checkpoint](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html#ckpt) is done.  You can find more information in the [SQLite docs](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your original database is **ImageDatabase** i.e name of database you give at the time of creation.
you can copy database and check the contain from [here](https://sqliteonline.com/)
upload your database in above link and you can verify it.