# Proper Way to annotate Android Room Dao?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-room, dao

I followed codelab tutorials and ended up with confusion. I want to use external db for testing purpose, the only one table and column(*word_table* and *word* as mentioned in codelab) works fine. But i'm trying to add my own created .db with following sql info:

```
CREATE TABLE "product_table" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "product"   TEXT,
    "partof"    TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("id")
);
```

I am not sure how to correctly annotate it. Following are the codes i'm using.

*WordDao.kt*

```
@Dao
interface WordDao {

@Query("SELECT * from product_table ORDER BY id ASC")
fun getAlphabetizedId(): List<Id>

@Query("SELECT * from product_table ORDER BY word ASC")
fun getAlphabetizedWords(): LiveData<List<Word>>

@Query("SELECT * from product_table ORDER BY partof ASC")
fun getAlphabetizedPartof(): List<Partof>
```

*Product.kt*

```
@Entity(tableName = "eilian_table")
class Id(@PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "id") val id: String)

@Entity(tableName = "eilian_table")
class Word(@ColumnInfo(name = "word") val word: String)

@Entity(tableName = "eilian_table")
class Partof(@ColumnInfo(name = "partof") val partof: String)
```

**Getting symbol and reference error.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look through [the docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data) - basically an `Entity` represents a table, you're creating three for the same table, and each one has one field. Here's your SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE "product_table" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "product"   TEXT,
    "partof"    TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("id")
);
```

So you want something like this:

```
@Entity(tablename = "product_table")
data class Product(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Int,
    val product: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "partof")
    val partOf: String
)
```

and you can see how it basically maps to the SQL - you might want to make the `String`s nullable, and I threw in the `@ColumnInfo` annotation just as an example of where the Kotlin field name is different from the column name in the table (even though it's case-insensitive so it doesn't actually matter here).

You'll need to change your queries so you're only pulling the columns you want out of the table

Comment: Ok thanks... umm.. hey btw my database is around 14 mb and creates extra -shm and -wal files (doubled the app size). Do you have any reference or info for that? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Someone's talking about them here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60665631/android-room-database-created-3-files-including-shm-and-wal-files It looks like they're basically SQLite database system files, don't worry about them!

Comment: Yay, got it. Thank you for the help.